# photoshop cs6 - how do i show actual palette colors

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Am fairly new to Photoshop. I want to see the actual palette I am using, I am doing some design work in which I am using a small number of colors eg under 20 for the entire image. Am currently playing with Posterize and/or Indexed colors to reduce images to the lower number of colors I need.

So I have a reduced palette, now how can I `see` it on screen? I would have assumed there would be an option to see it perhaps in one of the side windows such as `colors`.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the image format (or a copy of the image) to Index then:

Image → Mode → Color Table

You can now Save this Color Table and load it in the Swatches Panel.